# Reasons to remove ID's from Controls in on pages

Tags: asp.net, .net, performance, controls

It is possible to remove ID's from pages being renedered in .NET. This can be done by simply setting the ID tag of an element with the attribute runat="server" to null. Obviously this shouldn't be done for controls that have to be evaluated / used on postback scenarios. I am very curious on how widely removing ID's will be used by people knowing this can be done. I know that by removing ID values you are able to save some bandwith, but what should be a reason to start using this method?

Comment: I would see in the problem in an other way : why setting a control running at server if there is no need to reuse it later (and so getting it by its id) ? I see many people using `asp:label` for every text on the page... even if it's a static text. Most of time, a simple `span` tag is enough, or a `<%= %>` block

Comment: @Steve, I think that the main reason for using `asp:Label` is for rendering the content to different markup, by the user agent. However, as long as you expect only PC browsers, then perhaps the `span` \ `literal` \ `<%= %>` approach is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really concerned with performance I'd perhaps worry less about the verboseness of the .NET control IDs (which is a real pet dislike of mine) and worry more about the overall postback model.

The whole send the state to the client so that it can post it pack to the server is woefully inefficient in both latency and bandwidth terms.

If it's a new project it's probably worth use MVC instead, or if it's existing try turning page compression on in IIS.

Comment: I could not agree more with you Andy! Add to it Ajax.Net and the infamous "Partial Postbacks", which will add some extra couple of Kbs to each post with the ScriptManager and the UpdatePanels, and it seems people take this so lightly and even have Internet pages using this technology. If I was creating a brand new project, I would definitely use MVC as you suggested.