# How can I not send server-side only IDs to the client in the HTML?

Tags: html, asp.net, client-side, server-side

I'm working on an .aspx page that doesn't utilise any post backs for certain controls, so I don't need the IDs that are appearing on those controls in the HTML. I do need the IDs server side though as I'm doing some manipulations before sending.

Is there any way that I can not send them in the HTML? Really want to minimise loading size as this site gets smashed with views.

Comment: @mohammedmomn I don't see the need - this is a very generic situation. Imagine some basic ASP.NET control, like an asp:label, how can we have the ID not be sent to the client?

Comment: This post might be of interest as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294706/reasons-to-remove-ids-from-controls-in-on-pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, I would consider using another solution besides .net if this is a real concern. .net heavily relies on id's for pretty much everything.

You can remove them though for this specific reason.

```
public partial class SiteHomePage : MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // After you render the page in C#, remove the IDs.
    RemoveIDs();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reduce page size by 200 bytes by removing the ASP.NET ids.
    /// </summary>
    public void RemoveIDs()
    {
    Body1.ID = null;
    CategoryCountSpan1.ID = null;
    CategoryText1.ID = null;
    CategoryListItem1.ID = null;
    RssListItem1.ID = null;
    Prefix1.ID = null; // Shown in below example.
    Header1.ID = null; // Shown in below example.
    Author1.ID = null; // Shown in below example.
    BottomDivHome1.ID = null;
    BottomDivHome2.ID = null;
    JavaBlock1.ID = null;
    Advertisement1.ID = null;
    LogoLink1.ID = null;
    }
}
```

This was taken from [Dot Net Perls:ASP.NET Remove ID](http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-id) which is a great tutorial site.

Comment: Great, that's very usable and it works. We're happy to stick with .NET - it's our dev environment, it's the client's environment, and it's doing a great job so far. Hopefully with some of this ID nulling I can rip a dozen KB or so off the page!